# Likelihood function of a streched exponential function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, exponential-family

I would very much appreciate help regarding the following problem: I want to fit a stretched exponential function to different datasets by maximum likelihood:

$$y = e^{(b_0 x^{(b_1 - 1)} + b_2)}$$

$b_0$, $b_1$ and $b_2$ denote the parameters of the function, while "$x$" and "$y$" are variables. Unfortunately, my statistical skills are not sufficient in this area: Can anyone tell me the likelihood function of this stretched exponential function?

Comment: Likelihood makes no sense and cannot be determined until you specify a *probability model* for any discrepancies between observed values of $y$ and those predicted from the associated values of $x$.  What probability model would be appropriate in your application or might be suggested by the data?

Comment: Thank you very much whuber for your quick reply. I am not sure regarding your remarks. Basically, I want to replicate the results of a recently published paper ([link](http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/e18100364)). The authors estimate the entropy rate for natural language data. Since the true entropy rate is defined as a limit for an infinite amount of text and because the probabilistic model of natural language is unknown, the authors estimate the entropy for many different amounts of data and then use the ansatz function mentioned in my question to extrapolate.

Comment: So “x” is the amount of text (measured in characters) that is used to estimate the entropy rate “y”.

In their paper the authors fit a nonlinear regression where the square error between the predicted and the observed values is minimised. Now, I want to use Stata’s maximum likelihood capabilities ([link](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/maximum-likelihood-estimation/))  to fit this function. To this end, I want to specify an appropriate likelihood function that Stata maximize. I hope this helps to clarify my question. Many thanks again. Alex

Comment: When you are minimizing squared error, you are in effect assuming the errors are additive, independent, and have Normal distributions with a common variance.

Comment: Thanks again, 
I already tried to fit my data using non linear regressions. For several reasons (especially convergence), I would like to try using a maximum likelihood estimation approach.

Comment: You appear to contradict yourself.  Either you want to minimize the sum of squares of residuals or you do not.  If you do not, then we're back to the beginning: exactly how do you want to cope with discrepancies between the observed and fitted values of $y$?  "ML" isn't an answer--it's a technology to do the fitting after you have quantitatively answered that fundamental question.

Comment: I understand, but I am still not sure how to answer that question quantitatively. To fit via ML with Stata, I need to produce observation-by-observation values of the log likelihood. Or put differently, I need to write a program that evaluates the log likelihood, Stata then fits the model and obtains estimates

Comment: It is assumed that the overall log likelihood ln ln(L) is equal to the sum of all individual log likelihood values that are generated via the use- written program (or evaluator). For this program, I need to know the observation-by-observation log likelihood function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comments you suggest the model for an observation $Y$ associated with a regressor value $x$ is the one with homoscedastic Normal errors

$$Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\exp\left(b_0 x^{b_1-1} + b_2\right), \sigma^2\right)$$

and that different $Y$ are independent.  Writing $b=(b_0, b_1, b_2)$ and

$$\mu(x; b) = \exp\left(b_0 x^{b_1-1} + b_2\right),\tag{1}$$

we may therefore express the probability density function (PDF) of each observation $y_i$, $i=1,\ldots, n$ as

$$f_Y(y_i; x_i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y_i-\mu(x_i;b))^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

I'm pretty sure Stata wants you to supply the *log* likelihood function because in all but small problems the likelihood would underflow the IEEE double-precision floats it uses. The independence assumption implies the likelihood is the product of values of the PDF, whence its logarithm is the sum of their logarithms,

$$\eqalign{
\Lambda(y_1,\ldots,y_n; x_1,\ldots,x_n) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) - \frac{(y_i-\mu(x_i, b))^2}{2\sigma^2}\\
&=-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\mu(x_i, b))^2
.\tag{2}}$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ together provide an explicit formula for $\Lambda$ as a function of $b$ and $\sigma$ (depending, of course, on the data).

Note that conditional on any value of $\sigma$, maximizing $\Lambda$ amounts to finding $b$ to minimize the sum of squares of discrepancies between the $y_i$ and $\mu(x_i;b)$ (the right-hand term).

Except for huge datasets, maximizing $\Lambda$ accurately can be a delicate computation.  You can help your software out by finding some approximate initial solutions.  Consider exploring a set of reasonable values of $b_1$ and regressing (using ordinary least squares) $\log(y)$ against $x^{b_1-1}$ to estimate the slope $b_0$ and intercept $b_2$.  Pick the solution $\hat b = (\hat b_0, \hat b_1, \hat b_2)$ with the best fit and start Stata's search at $\hat b$.  If you can, supply some bounds for these parameters so it can constrain that search.

Comment: Dear whuber, I will try to implement your solution tomorrow. Thank you, very much appreciated!